# Multiplying the voltage output

Tags: arduino-uno, voltage

I'm working on a project where my arduino is receiving a voltage 0-5V, I need the output to be 10V always. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You get a power supply that gives 10V and switch it using the Arduino (just like you would with a relay or a motor). Or if you need analog between 0-10V you amplify it (again with a 10V or higher power supply) with an op-amp.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Could you please be more specific about your task? Unfortunately there are multiple interpretations of what you wrote so far. Is your input signal analog (0 to 5 V) or digital (just high and low)? If analog how is your intended relation of the output to the input (multiplication implies an analog relation, i.e. in 0V - out 0V, in 2V - out 4V, in 5V - out 10V) or do you mean that if the input is low (or if analog below a certain threshold) the output should be 0V and if the input is high (analog above threshold) the output should be 10V? [...]

Comment: [...] Do you want to drive a certain load with that 10V? If recommending a specific setup (i.e. transistor circuit) that might make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the 0-5 Volts is supposed to switch the output, in which case you want a program to control your output, then you will want to use a digital output pin to either switch a relay or a transistor that controls the 10 Volts put out to whatever it is that you are controlling.

Perhaps you want PWM which indicates a transistor circuit.  Hard to tell what you want from the way this is worded.

Taking your words literaly, "I need the output to be 10V always" then that simply means hard-wiring to a 10V power supply.   ;-)